# To prevent text wrap in TexPad editor

Tags: text-editor

I did not find anywhere such an option. 
I do not want this

[image]

How can you prevent text wrap in TexPad editor?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. 
I switched to TextMate which is much more sufficient for my needs. 
Some review about integrated editors [here](http://www.imore.com/best-free-and-paid-text-editors-mac) where some open sourcing of the excellent editors has happened.